# How can you access managed objects created by different Realm instances?

Tags: android, realm

I have created an application in Android that uses realm.

I have a splash screen that loads all the data needed to operate, and a number of activities that use that data.

That data is stored in an Application class extension as static variables.

My problem is that when I try to manipulate the data in other activities I get an error about the realm database being closed.

I have solved this by creating a static reference to my database on Application. Opening it in `OnCreate()` and closing it in `OnTerminate()` but I get the feeling that this is wrong.

I have also solved it by creating unmanaged objects (i.e. after retrieving them from Realm using copyFromRealm) and then when I need to do alterations copying them back into a realm instance I just created.

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a splash screen that loads all the data needed to operate, and a number of activities that use that data.
>
> That data is stored in an Application class extension as static variables.

That's *very* interesting - have you tried to put the application in background on a screen, then go to Android Studio's **Logcat** tab, go to the additional menu items in the bottom left, and click TERMINATE?

[image: terminate button]

Fun fact is that if your application is in background when you do this, and then you re-open the app from the launcher, you'll have the exact same effect as if your app had been killed via low memory condition.

In your case, you'll just crash with an NPE on pretty much any screen that is not the splash screen! Very, very interesting.

(Also, `Application.onTerminate()` is never called. So that's not helpful either.)

---

Anyways, to get back to your original question,

> My problem is that when I try to manipulate the data in other activities I get an error about the realm database being closed.
>
> What is the correct way to solve this problem?

The section [Best Practices: Controlling the lifecycle of Realm instances](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-instance-lifecycle) section of the official documentation is fairly helpful in this regard.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Realm realm;
    private RealmResults<Dog> dogs;
    private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Dog>> realmChangeListener = (results) -> {
         // do something on first load + future changes of Dogs
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dogs = realm.where(Dog.class).sort("age").findAllAsync();
        dogs.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dogs.removeAllChangeListeners();
        dogs = null;
        realm.close();
        realm = null;
    }
}
```

or

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private Realm realm;
    private RealmResults<Dog> dogs;
    private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Dog>> realmChangeListener = (results) -> {
         // do something on first load + future changes of Dogs
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        dogs = realm.where(Dog.class).sort("age").findAllAsync();
        dogs.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        dogs.removeAllChangeListeners();
        dogs = null;
        realm.close();
        realm = null;
    }
}
```

Realm instances are ref-counted on a given thraead, so I guess the answer is, "keep one open while you need it". And of course, close it when you no longer do.